# How to learn stored procedure authorization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Are there any query to learn which user authorized for which stored procedure (sp) ?

For example there are 100 stored procedures and there are 2 user who are guests and normal

how can I learn which one is authorized for which sp?

I wonder that and I want to know are there any method for this? 
I dont know there is or not.

(For MSSQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these links out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx

```
--EXECUTE AS USER = 'Wanida';
SELECT * 
FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.MyProc','OBJECT') 
ORDER BY subentity_name, permission_name;
```

Comment: If you want to find who can use the above proc I used in the example, create a loop with all the users calling this and that should tell you.

Comment: When I want to execute above query, I have got an error. "Incorrect syntax near 'OBJECT'."  For second parameter, what is the meaning of 'OBJECT'?

Comment: Updated, the error was due to a missing comma.  OBJECT is used when running this function for a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice that. Therein, I think I should get the users with "SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals" and create a loop and the query will tell me the which user has which permission. Isn't it?

Comment: Correct loop through the users and issue EXECUTE AS USER = 'AuserName'; before you run the query.